# Using Python to send message to Flume Avro Source

Tags: python, cloudera, flume, avro

I would like to write a Python program to convert a stream of JSON documents to Avro and stream them to Flume (so I can send them onto to Solr and Parquet).

I am looking at an example that uses the Python avro library, which claims to implement the avro rpc protocol. https://github.com/phunt/avro-rpc-quickstart/blob/master/src/main/python/send_message.py

But when I try and send the example to my Flume Avro server, it seems that it just closes the connection. E.g.

```
$ ./atest.py jnkjn kjnkjn e3e3
Have requester
About to request... REQUEST>Ú­òs±3ô8RÍsÊT¿ÌQÚ­òs±3ô8RÍsÊT¿Ìsend
jnkjn
     kjnkje3e3<
RESPONSE><
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "atest.py", line 35, in <module>
    print("Result: " + requestor.request('send', params))
  ...
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 991, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 392, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 356, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine
```

I had to put a XXX print statement in HTTPLIB to see the response was just empty, or the connection was closed.

Am I even on the write track by pointing the avro Python library at a Flume Avro Source? Do they even talk the same protocol?

I am running the latest CDH5.1 stack.

Checking the Flume logs, I noticed there is a very specific error that is thrown whenever I try and connect:

```
2014-09-16 16:35:15,745 INFO org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyServer: [id: 0x0633c6d1, /192.168.150.84:38516 => /172.31.1.204:19999] OPEN
2014-09-16 16:35:15,745 INFO org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyServer: [id: 0x0633c6d1, /192.168.150.84:38516 => /172.31.1.204:19999] BOUND: /172.31.1.204:19999
2014-09-16 16:35:15,746 INFO org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyServer: [id: 0x0633c6d1, /192.168.150.84:38516 => /172.31.1.204:19999] CONNECTED: /192.168.150.84:38516
2014-09-16 16:35:15,747 INFO org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyServer: [id: 0x0633c6d1, /192.168.150.84:38516 :> /172.31.1.204:19999] DISCONNECTED
2014-09-16 16:35:15,747 INFO org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyServer: [id: 0x0633c6d1, /192.168.150.84:38516 :> /172.31.1.204:19999] UNBOUND
2014-09-16 16:35:15,747 INFO org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyServer: [id: 0x0633c6d1, /192.168.150.84:38516 :> /172.31.1.204:19999] CLOSED
2014-09-16 16:35:15,747 INFO org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyServer: Connection to /192.168.150.84:38516 disconnected.
2014-09-16 16:35:15,747 WARN org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyServer: Unexpected exception from downstream.
org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Excessively large list allocation request detected: 539959368 items! Connection closed.
    at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransportCodec$NettyFrameDecoder.decodePackHeader(NettyTransportCodec.java:167)
    at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransportCodec$NettyFrameDecoder.decode(NettyTransportCodec.java:139)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:422)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:84)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:471)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:332)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: @MatthewMoisen Yes, Flume is a pile of rubbish, as is morphlines. I  ended up writing a Python program to talk to the Solr JSON api directly, and also to convert to Avro and stick it onto HDFS via HttpFS. Then I sucked them into the Hive metastore through an external table, where I could process them in Impala and convert them to Parquet (using an Impala select/insert). The nice things about going direct to the Solr JSON api is it will allow the submission of nested documents (when CDH includes a newer version of Solr that includes this), which morphlines will never ever do.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this problem, it was due to insufficient buffer size of flume channel.
Adjusted the buffer size of the channel to get it resolved.

For memory channel the property is : ***byteCapacityBufferPercentage***